# Сделать вывод ошибки в регистрации

Tags: php, javascript

Как вывести ошибку в регистрации и чтоб не шел на файл php, этой регистрации.
2 разных файла 1файл index.php где форма регистрации, а другой company_registration.php , при ошибки он переходит на этот файл company_registration.php. А надо чтоб в форме выводил ошибку. Как это сделать

index.php

> ```
>                       <form role="form" method="post" action="../registration/company_registration.php">
> <div class="field"><label for="name">Your Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="" placeholder="Your email" /></div>
> ```

company_registration.php

```
if(!filter_var($company_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo"<script>alert('Please enter the email')</script>";
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример на ajax конкретно для вашей задачи:

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="registration_form" action="../registration/company_registration.php">
<div class="registration_form_error" style="display: none; color: red;"></div>
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Your Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="" placeholder="Your email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Registration">
</div>
</form>
```

Скрипт

```
$("#registration_form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../registration/company_registration.php',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            var res = JSON.parse(data); // Парсим json
            if (res.status == 'success') {
                // Действия при успешной регистрации.
                $('.registration_form_error').hide();
                alert(res.message);
            } else {
                // Действия при не успешной регистрации.
                $('.registration_form_error').text(res.message);
                $('.registration_form_error').show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Обработка php

```
<?php //../registration/company_registration.php
$result = []; // Будем обратно отдавать json.

if(!filter_var($company_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    // Валидация не пройдена
    $result['status'] = 'error';
    $result['message'] = 'Please enter the email!';
    exit (json_encode($result)); // Выходим и превращаем массив $result в json
}else{
    // Валидация пройдена
    $result['status'] = 'success';
    $result['message'] = 'Registration success!';
    exit (json_encode($result)); // Выходим и превращаем массив $result в json
}
?>
```